# Extracting lat long data from existing polyline

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Does anyone know how to extract the la long coordinates from an existing MKPolyline? I need them to build out a parameter around a trail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MKPolyline *line = ....;

for(i = 0; i < line.pointCount; i++) {
   CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(line.points[i]);
   // use coord.latitude && coord.longitude
}
```